# Questions regarding uploading files to Amazon S3 using browser based HTTP POST

Tags: security, file-upload, amazon-s3

I have a couple of questions regarding uploading files to Amazon S3 directly by the user using HTTP POST form generated by a JSP page

- The access key and the signature
  needs to be exposed to the user to
  allow him to upload files from a JSP
  form. In the signature I have to set
  the expiration time or else by
  default it’s valid for 15 minutes.

  i) Can the user use these details to    upload to S3 outside my portal to    update his files or update/modify    others files.

  ii). How can I set the policy to avoid this ?
- Can the user use the signature for
  multiple requests ? If yes how to
  stop the user from doing multiple
  uploads ? How do I ensure that the
  user can use this signature with a
  request only once ?
- Sometimes there might be problems at
  Amazon S3 with latencies and uploads.
  If the response from S3 takes time
  and the user tries to upload the file
  again. He will receive a exception,
  how can I handle this ?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

The public access key cannot be used for anything without the secret key. **Never expose your secret key.**

As long as you sign the policy on the server you are safe. The signature is only valid for the time you specify and for uploading to a specific bucket and key. Without your secret key, the user has no way to create another signature to upload any other files.

They cannot access any other files.

As far as I am aware, the signature expiry time only needs to be valid while they initiate the upload so you can set a pretty short time.

Answer (score 0):

> i) Can the user use these details to upload to S3 outside my portal to
>   update his files or update/modify others files.

Yes, the user can use these details to replay the action. You can specify the file name so he can only update the file he upload.

> ii). How can I set the policy to avoid this ?

You can add some other conditions to limit the access. Like "expiration", set it to 5/10 minutes after the signature generated. And you can add any other conditions, like "user_id" or something else.